# What is the default carrier frequency of matlab's pskmod?

Tags: matlab

I'm using the matlab function [pskmod](http://in.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/pskmod.html) for modulating a bit string. What is the carrier frequency used by default by the function?

Comment: It's baseband modulation so no carrier right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `pskmod.m` returns a vector of complex baseband symbols. Each element of that vector has the form $y_k=e^{j(2\pi m(k)/M+\phi) }$, where $M$ is the alphabet size, $m(k)$ is an integer between $0$ and $M-1$ which depends on the message symbol at time $k$, and $\phi$ is some initial phase (which defaults to $0$).

There is no carrier involved, and for simulation purposes it's usually also not necessary to use one because a digital communication system can be simulated by using the equivalent baseband system.